# Drop Down Overlapping, Image Slider IE8, Joomla

Tags: html, css, joomla, internet-explorer-8, joomla2.5

I have installed a drop down module/menu on this joomla 2.5 webpage here named 'Call us' top right:

[Go to website here >>](http://www.goldstarclean.co.uk/)

However when viewing this in internet explorer 8 the image slider/module overlaps the menu. I have tried putting a z-index in the CSS styling but it's not working.

Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

well, try this one 
http://aplus.rs/lab/z-pos/ 
or
http://www.brenelz.com/blog/2009/02/03/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/
it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

check zindex value in slider division . If its there you can check the menu zindex value. Add position: relative in that slier division. The menu zindex value should greater than the slider zinex. value.
Hope this will helps u.....